Setup Craft CMS 5 webroot to htdocs
For a Craft CMS 5 project installed with ddev, how can we make the webroot folder become /htdocs instead of /web?
Is this something to be reconfigured after installation, or does it need to be done strictly during installation?"

In your project root is a hidden .ddev directory. Inside of that directory, edit the config.yaml file and change docroot: web to docroot: htdocs.
Restart DDEV.
You'll also need to update your Craft .env file, so it knows the new web root. Change CRAFT_WEB_ROOT="/var/www/html/web" to CRAFT_WEB_ROOT="/var/www/html/htdocs".
